# Software or python package to draw and plot simple objects in 3D?

Tags: python, graphics

I am looking for a software package, or even better, a python package that allows me to draw objects by inputing parameters, for example: I want a circle at position x,y, radius r, thickness t, color c and then look at it at different angles.

I know that I could use stuff like blender, but I feel that this is overkill and it would take a long time to learn it sufficiently.

I just need this to do some ncie looking plots in my thesis.

thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend [OpenSCad](http://www.openscad.org). It is a software to create 3D objects by writing code. Although it isn't a python package, it is quite lightweight, has a nice view and the commands are really easy to learn - take a look at their [Cheat Sheet](http://www.openscad.org/documentation.html). The projects can be shared as text files or exported in various 3D formats, to get a prettier view from other software.

Comment: Thanks! That looks promising. I will try it out.

Answer (score 2):

And I you want to do the same but stick with Python you can combine OpenSCAD with [SolidPython](https://github.com/SolidCode/SolidPython).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Glass Engine](https://pypi.org/project/glass-engine/) to do this. To install it, just use `pip install glass-engine`. If you want to draw a thick circle, in fact, it's a cylinder side, you can use following code:

```py
from glass_engine import *
from glass_engine.Geometries import *

scene, camera, light = ModelView()

model = CylinderSide(radius=0.5, height=1, color=glm.vec3(1,0,0))
model.position.z = -0.5 # set position
# model.color = glm.vec3(..., ..., ...) # change color to other value
# model.radius = 0.7 # change radius to other value
# model.height = 1.2 # change height to other value

scene.add(model)

camera.screen.show()
```

Then you can get following result: [thick circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPphm.png)

You can drag mouse left button to rotate, right button to translate.

If you want to draw more geometries in scene:

```py
from glass_engine import *
from glass_engine.Geometries import *

scene, camera, light, floor = SceneRoam()

geoms = \
[
    Sphere(radius=0.5)    , Cone(radius=0.5)        , Cylinder(radius=0.5),
    Box(Lx=0.7)           , Prism(radius=0.5)       , Pyramid(radius=0.5),
    Octahedron(radius=0.5), Dodecahedron(radius=0.5), Icosahedron(radius=0.5)
]

for i in range(len(geoms)):
    geoms[i].position.x = 2*(i % 3 - 1)
    geoms[i].position.y = 2*(1 - i // 3)
    geoms[i].position.z -= geoms[i].z_min
    scene.add(geoms[i])

camera.screen.show()
```

Then you can get: [multi geometries in scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHIVl.png)

In this example, you can use <kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> to roam in scene, and drag mouse right button to rotate.

[Glass Engine](https://pypi.org/project/glass-engine/) support over 40 kinds of geometries. All geometries can set a lot of parameters you want. And you can define your own shape by specify vertices and indices. It can also load model from file(support over 40 kinds of file formats).

See full document at: https://glass-engine-doc.readthedocs.io/zh/latest/